# Check who has logged in using SQL Server 2000 trc files

Tags: sql-server-2000

I'm trying to go through multiple `.trc` files to find out who has been logging into SQL Server over the last few months. I didn't setup the trace, but what I've got are a bunch of `.trc` files,

ex:

- `C:\SQLAuditFile2012322132923.trc`,
- `C:\SQLAuditFile201232131931.trc`

etc.

I can load these files into SQL Profiler and look at them individually, but I was hoping for a way to load them all up, so that I can quickly scan them for logins. Either using a filter, or better yet, load them into a SQL Server table and query them.

I tried loading the files into a table using:

```
 use <databasename>
 GO
 SELECT * INTO trc_table
 FROM ::fn_trace_gettable('C:\SQLAuditFile2012322132923.trc', 10);
 GO
```

But when I do this, i get the error message:

> File 'C:\SQLAuditFile2012322132923.trc' either does not exist or is not a recognizable trace file. Or there was an error opening the file.

However, I know the file exists, and I have the correct name. Also they appear to be recognizable because I can load them up into SQL Profiler and view them fine.

Anybody have an idea why I'm getting this error message, and if this won't work, perhaps another way of analyzing these multiple .trc files more easily?

Thanks!

Comment: When you try to import the file into SQL Server - does the file exists **on the server's C:\ drive**?? That's where it'll be looking - not on your *local* C:\ drive, but the **server machine's**

Comment: @marc_s great point, one I usually ignore altogether here because most folks are dealing with local, not remote, instances. So russ, are you running this command on the server, and are the .trc files on the server?

Comment: Thanks - Yes the file exists on the servers C drive.  I'm rdp into the server it's self, so i'm running the command from within SQL Query Analyzer on the server, which is looking for the file on the C drive of the same server.

Comment: Thank you both.  Some how it was a permissions problem.  I followed the instructions [here](http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2011/04/msg-567-level-16-state-7-line-1-file.html) which basically recommends sharing the folder, and accessing it like '\\server\share' and that seemed to work fine.  Maybe i'm missing something, but I thought since i logged in as admin, and sql was running as admin, i would have permissions to read it.

Comment: You shouldn't need to share a folder, unless you insist on leaving the files in the root (which, depending on your OS, may still have certain restrictions). I suggest you keep these files in a subfolder, as my answer suggested - permissions should be less of an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be having permissions issues on the root of C:. Try placing the file into a subfolder, e.g. c:\tracefiles\, and ensuring that the SQL Server account has at least explicit read permissions on that folder.

Also try starting simpler, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM ::fn_trace_gettable('C:\SQLAuditFile2012322132923.trc', default);
```

Anyway unless you were explicitly capturing successful login events, I don't know that these trace files are going to contain the information you're looking for... this isn't something SQL Server tracks by default.

Comment: Thank you, I did check permissions, and I'm domain admin on SQL server, and on the machine.  Using the same account, i'm able to create/delete files on the root of C.  The simpler SQL command gives me the same error.  Also, the trace logs do contain the data I need, because when I load them up individually into SQL Profiler, the username is a column I see, and it does contain the various usernames that have logged in - both successfully and unsuccessfully.

Comment: Yes, *you* are able to do that. But when you tell SQL Server to run a command, SQL Server does not impersonate you. The SQL Server service account is the account that is trying to read the file from C:\

Comment: Ah, thanks, I checked permissions on the SQL Server Service, and that's running using the domain admin account as well.

Comment: Well I am not sure what else could make SQL Server think it wasn't a valid trace file. Have you tried loading it from a different instance of SQL Server?

Comment: It ended up being a permissions issue, even though all accounts were admin accounts, something was up, and when i tinkered with it, i got it to work.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty much the same issue and thought I'd copy [my solution from
Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71551/43789).

I ran an SQL trace on a remote server and transferred the trace files to a
local directory on my workstation so that I load the data into a table on my
local SQL Server instance for running queries against.

At first I thought the error might be related permission but I ruled this
out since I had no problem loading the .trc files directly into SQL Profiler
or as a file into SSMS.

After trying a few other ideas, I thought about it a bit more and realised
that it was due to permissions after all: the query was being run by the SQL
Server process (sqlsrvr.exe) as the user `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` –
not my own Windows account.

The solution was to grant **Read** and **Execute** permissions to `NETWORK
SERVICE` on the directory that the trace files were stored in and the trace
files themselves.

You can do this by right-clicking on the directory, go to the *Security*
tab, add `NETWORK SERVICE` as a user and then select `Read & Execute` for
its Permissions (this should automatically also select `Read` and
`List folder contents`). These file permissions (ACLs) should automatically
propagate to the directory contents.

If you prefer to use the command line, you can grant the necessary permissions to
the directory – and its contents – by running the following:

```
icacls C:\Users\anthony\Documents\SQL_traces /t /grant "Network Service:(RX)"
```